# Regex python Match after and before a specific string

Tags: python, regex, list, web-scraping, split

Lets say we have this
string:"Code:*1*,Some text some other text {fdf: more text, **attr**=*important* "

I want to catch the pattern using Regex that can findall **attr** and extract *important* and *1* and put them in dict.

I tried [this one](https://regex101.com/r/AS9IaK/1):

```
(?<=testcaseid_)[^_]+_[^_]+
```

but still capture all the previous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand well, but if you want to get everything **starts from "1"** to something **after attr=** you can also use regex like this:

```
r"1.*?attr=\w+"
```